# Scrollable textarea in Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, scroll, textarea

I have some textarea elements where a user can enter a message to a companion.

These are presented in a modal in the Phonegap WebView.

When the modal is present on screen I disable the scrolling on the WebView body like so:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Likewise when I hide the modal I re-enable it like so:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
    return true;
};
```

The textarea elements do not seem to be able to scroll on touch events.  I looked into this and tried applying the following CSS:

```
overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

But this did not help.

When the user enters some long text the textarea moves in line with the amount of text but a user cannot scroll back to a previous position.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What happend if you don't disable the scroll when your modal is on the screen ? can you scroll on the textarea ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just look to see if the move event was coming from a textarea and allow those events to pass through.

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){ 
    if(e.srcElement.type !== "textarea"){ 
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
};
```

Answer (score -2):

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>`

Add jquery Mobile js in head tag .. it will work